Pagination when entity has relations in Spring Data R2DBC
I have an entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employees")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private String id;

    @Column("photo_url")
    private String photoUrl;

    @Column("description")
    private String description;

    @Transient
    private UserEntity user;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = false;
}

and
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(value = "id")
    private String id;

    @Deprecated
    @Column(value = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = false;
}

but when i try get all employees with pagination like that
@Query("""
            SELECT *
            FROM employees e
            LEFT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.id
            WHERE e.dealer_id = :id
            """)
    Flux<EmployeeEntity> findAllByDealerId(String id, Pageable pageable);

the User in Employee always null.
Pageable can containe sort key word from both entities, thats why i need to join theese tables. If someone know why user always null or someone know another way to get employees with user and pageable it would be very nice :)

You've marked it as Transient, how can it be anything but null?

@lane.maxwell i tried remove it, but it doesn't work

Since it's another object, you also will need to configure the mappings appropriately.  I assume this is a OneToOne relationship, so you'll need to add this to your model.  Look for the docs for mapping OneToOne, OneToMany, etc

Spring Data R2dbc/R2dbc does not support one to one, one to many relations as JPA, for the complex query I suggest use jOOQ instead, jOOQ has added R2dbc support. We have used jOOQ for R2dbc in production for over two years.
Check my jOOQ query example project which include one to many relation,
https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/jooq/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L174-L213
